# Java nested self referential generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a class which has a self referential generic parameter and a parameter which is of the same super class. The static function has identical bounds as the class.

```
public class Bar<T extends Bar<T, C>, C extends Bar<C, ?>> {

    Bar() {
        foo((T) null);
        foo((C) null);//compile error
    }

    static <S_T extends Bar<S_T, S_C>, S_C extends Bar<S_C, ?>> void foo(S_T t) {
    }
}
```

This gives the following error.

> Bound mismatch: The generic method foo(S_T) of type Bar<T,C> is not
>   applicable for the arguments (C). The inferred type C is not a valid
>   substitute for the bounded parameter <S_T extends Bar<S_T,S_C>>

I can't figure out why `C` can't be passed in to `foo()` since `C` is `Bar<C,?>` and the wildcard is a `Bar` because of the second parameter in the declaration says it extends Bar.

I know this is probably a bad idea and produces code which is hard to understand but I really wanna know why this doesn't compile.

Comment: possibly related to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937422/a-bad-interaction-between-self-referential-types-and-bounded-wildcards

Comment: @JudgeMental somewhat similar; but from what I gathered from your question it's the class hierarchy that failed to compile, while my class hierarchy compiles but fails on the argument constraint for the function.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that Java type inference is actually pretty lame.

Java is not performing any intelligent inference on the wildcard `?` in the declaration of `Bar` to infer that it is logically bounded by `Bar< ?, ? >` (nor that the `?`s in that bound are themselves bounded, and so on).  Once you put `?` by itself, that's all Java knows.  Although nothing is stopping you from putting that bound in on the wildcard in the declaration of `Bar`, even that does not help Java; Java won't ever assume that two separate `?`s refer to the same type, even if deeper analysis would imply that they have to be.  In other words, the compile error persists even with this code:

```
public class Bar<T extends Bar<T, C>, C extends Bar<C, ? extends Bar<?, ? extends Bar<?, ?>>>> {

    Bar() {
        foo((T) null);
        foo((C) null);//compile error
    }

    static <S_T extends Bar<S_T, S_C>, S_C extends Bar<S_C, ? extends Bar<?, ? extends Bar<?, ?>>>> void foo(S_T t) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I started to suspect that java couldn't detect the connection between the wildcard bounds. 

I started experimenting with supplying a class: `Pie extends Bar<Pie,Pie>` instead of the wildcard. Then the function would have `<S_T extends Bar<S_T,S_C>, S_C extends Bar<S_C,Pie>` and one could still have methods on Bar which would return S_C....But I might be completly off target now (almost 3am here)

Comment: what would be wrong with `Bar< S_T, S_C >` as the argument type to `foo`?  The only information you can use about `S_T` in `foo` is that it is a `Bar< S_T, S_C >` anyway.  Plus that makes `foo` (theoretically, at least) more general.

Comment: What would be the generic parameters for the function? Do you mean just defining S_T and S_C without any bounds, because then Bar<S_T,S_C> in the argument won't match the bounds for the Bar class

Comment: Right, that doesn't help much.  It occurs to me that if you want to call `foo( ( C )null )`, you don't care about the second parameter to `Bar` in `foo` either, which means why not just `static <S_T extends Bar<S_T, ?>> void foo( S_T t ) {}` ?

Comment: Well that kinda works, depending of what one want to do, since you can't call `new Bar<S_T,S_C>()` if you have a wildcard instead of S_C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a crack with generics, but I think the problem is that you declare the type of foo() to be

```
<S_T extends Bar<S_T,S_C> > void foo(S_T)
```

and then call it in two different contexts that require a different static type for `foo()`.

In the fist context `S_T` has type `T` and in the second context it has type `C`. But `T` and `C` are declared as `Bar<T,?>` and `Bar<C,?>`, which are incompatible types statically. 
I would guess that the compiler figures out the type of `foo()` in the first call and then assumes correctly, that the type must remain the same throughout, which it doesn't.

Comment: Switching the order of the two foo() calls still gives an error on the line with the C.

Comment: OK, try changing the order of C and T in the class declaration, ie. do Bar<C extends Bar<C,T>, T extends Bar<T,?>. If the error flips then, it means that the type bindings also depend on the order of the types in the class declaration. But in either case, C and T have different incompatible types and you can't pass both into foo().

Comment: I tried the change you suggested and the error changed to T but I think that's simply because all it did was rename the parameters, not change any meaning. I tried a couple of different ways of reording the parameters and the error stays on the parameter which has the wildcard.
Also I think that although C and T are incompatible with eachother both should be compatible with the static function since AFAIK its generic parameters are based on the input it get each call.